# Is it possible to store a database server connection during a Node server restart?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, knex.js

After successfully logging in, every user in the application receives an authorization token and dedicated SQL server connection.

When Node server receives a request, it checks for authorization token, and if it's valid - makes a request to the database using a connection, that has been dedicated for the user.

The token and the connection is stored in the regular JSON object, which is cleared after Node server has been restarted. Therefore, users have to enter their SQL sever credentials once again.

Since my API is not stable, I would need to restart Node server frequently, and that would cause some inconvenience to users.

The reason I am using dedicated connection is the ability to manage users' access on the SQL server level (granting access to certain tables or views), and to use SUSER_SNAME() function in order to log users' activities. This approach also allows me to implement a row-level security model.

Or maybe there is a way to store some kind of token for the SQL sever session, that would allow to connect to the server without providing user credentials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix mispelling in the question title.  I'm honestly not sure what you meant it to say or I'd fix it myself.  I don't think you "sore a database" so something is amiss.

Comment: @jfriend00 My apologies. It's fixed now.

Comment: I guess it kind of goes without saying that it would be better to fix your API and make it stable so you don't have to restart your node server regularly.  If I was going to invest a bunch of engineering to fix this issue, that seems like a better place to spend your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store a database connection during a server restart.  The connection belongs to a particular process so when that process is killed the connection is killed too.

There are some things you could do:

1. Move the database connections to a custom proxy process that does not get restarted and your node app just reconnects to the proxy.  This would allow the actual database connections to be retained in the proxy while your node.js server restarts.
2. Store the user credentials in a local database so when your node.js server restarts, you can reconnect to the database without asking the user to supply their credentials again.  This has obvious security implications.
3. Fix the stability of your API so your node.js server does not have to be restarted very often.

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide any references on how custom proxy process can be implemented?

Comment: @FlashDark - In this case it would just be a server of its own that was a holder of your DB connections with some simple API to create a connection and to send a request on it.